# Complexity of algorithm in Big O notation

Tags: java, big-o, complexity-theory

Consider the following code snippet:

```
for(int index = 1;index < N;index*=2){
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < N){
       counter++;
    }
}
```

Determine its best - and worst - case runtime in the Big Theta notation as a function of N.
Options:

a) Best case: O(log(N)) - Worst case: O(N²)

b) Best case: O(N . log(N)) - Worst case: O(N . log(N))

c) Best case: O(N . log(N)) - Worst case: O(N²)

d) Best case: O(N) - Worst case: O(N)

I saw this question in a Java assessment and I really don't know the right answer.
I answered the option D, but I don't know if it is right.
Could you help me with that?

Comment: Because of the `*=2` in the outer loop, it iterates `log(N)` times. The inner loop should be obvious, it loops `N` times.

Comment: You should explain why you thought it was *d* to get a better learning effect. This way people are able to address and fix your misunderstandings.

Answer (score 3):

This is `O(NlogN)` both best and worst case.

The inner loop repeats itself everytime it starts exactly the same number of times, which is `N` times.

The outer loop repeats itself `logN` times.

So, if you combine these, the total number of times `counter` is increased is:

```
T(n) = N + N + ... + N = N*logN
```

Which gives you total of `O(NlogN)` time.

Comment: **Bonus**: If the inner loop would have been `while(counter < index){`, this would have changed the answer, now it would have been `O(N)` for both, since the total number of repeats is now: `1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + N/2 + N`, which is `<2N`.

Comment: I thought that logN will always be in recursive functions. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Recursion is in no way faster than iteration, it's just a 'cleaner' way sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop runs `N` times, so each cycle of the outer loop is `O(N)`.
The outer loop has its index increasing exponentially, then we can say it needs `log(N)` cycles.

Put them together and you'll have `N log(N)` in both cases as there isn't any "best" or "worse" condition, there's no way to exit that loop other than doing them all.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer is N log N for both best and worst case

To start with, there is no short-circuiting. Which means best case must be the same as worst case

Second, The outer loop is going to run log(N) times, as index is doubled in every loop

Third, the inner loop accumulates from 0 to N - 1 stepping by one each time. So that's N operations

Thus N log N for both best and worst